# Magento 2: How to display custom attribute in catalog?

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-attributes

I’ve created a new textfield attribute, with the following settings set to yes:

```
Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront
Used in Product Listing
```

The attribute is assigned to an attribute set and it shows up in the product view as intended.

However it’s not visible in the catalog view, I’m using the **default Luma theme** and I’ve cleared cache and re-indexed. If I view the template file:

```
magento-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

I can’t find any code getting custom attributes, so the Luma theme doesn’t seem to support this by default.

How can I get a products custom attribute label and value in **list.phtml**?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We can get custom attribute value like below

**Attribute Value**

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

**Label**

```
$address =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getStoreLabel();
```

> Note : in above line **c_address** is my custom attribute code.

**Reference:** `Magento/Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`

Comment: it not works if attribute is a `media image` type.

Comment: @Bilal, for me custom attributes are showing "fatal error getFrontend" in list.phtml. can you tell please how to avoid this error please if you have any idea

Answer (score 14):

I created an article about this, that have only **5 steps** to do it:

1 - Create your attribute in **Stores > Attributes > Product**.

2 - Set the attribute in the Default group, go to **Stores > Attributes > Attribute Set**.

3 - Set the values of this attributes in your products.

4 - Open in your custom theme the relative file below:

```
app/design/frontend/CUSTOM/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

5 - Between the foreach function paste this code below, but changing the code of your correct attribute:

```
$_getMyAttr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');

if ($_getMyAttr){

    // Get Value
    $attrTestValue = $_getMyAttr->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

    // Get Label
    $attrTestLabel = $_getMyAttr->getStoreLabel();
}
```

## Important

> Make sure **“Visible on Product View Page on Front-end”**
>   and **“Used in Product Listing”** options under storefront Properties
>   are set to Yes.

Reference: https://rafaelstz.github.io/magento/magento2-display-custom-attribute-catalog-list-products.html

Comment: With `media image` attribute ”Visible on Product View Page on Front-end” and “Used in Product Listing” are not settable.

Comment: same for price attribute

Comment: where can I find the default list.phtml ?

Comment: hello, attribute label is working for me but not attribute value

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('identifier'); 
if ($attribute) 
{ 
$attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@mikebertiean To find the default list.phtml navigate to

`<Magento base>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product`

Once you've copied it and altered it and added it to the path that Rafael mentioned, you should just need to flush your cache and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

since the `$_product->getResource()` has been deprecated I tried to find another solution and I found a simpler way to display the product attribute:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')
```

Here is the original response: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/297442/95081

Comment: Thanks! This should be the new accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open

```
app/design/frontend/CUSTOM/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Add the following between foreach loop.

```
<?php

$brand_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand');

if ($brand_attribute){

    // Get Value
    $brand_value = $brand_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

    // Get Label
    $brand_lable = $brand_attribute->getStoreLabel();
    echo $brand_lable." : ".$brand_value;
}

?>
```