# getResource is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: magento2, deprecated, getresource

getResource() is deprecated so my question is what do I need to use instead to be future proof for next updates.

I use this function like below in the catalog list.phtml

```
$seedBank = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get product custom attribute option label directly as below:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('brand');
```

This will return label of product selected brand.

Comment: Awesome, that worked like a charm !

Answer (score 4):

Have an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product` as a dependency for your class and call methods from that class.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
 */

private $productResource;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResource,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->productResource = $productResource;
    ....
}
```

Now, in the methods where you need the value, let's say `$_product` is the product instance you can do this:

```
$seedBank = $this->productResource->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work on other pages. On the Category page the following will be enough:
$_product->getAttributeText('brand');

Comment: $this->productResource->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); not productResource() is not a function