# Get Grouped Products Associated Child Product Custom Attribute

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, grouped-products

I've created a few product attributes with these settings:

- Scope: Store View
- Add to Column Options: Yes
- Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront: Yes
- Used in Product Listing: Yes
- Used for sorting in Product Listing: Yes

In my grouped product, I have a value:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But, in my custom `/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml` file, I've got this:

```
<?php
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/trey.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    foreach ($_item->getAttributes() as $attr)
    {
        $logger->info(
            $attr->getAttributeCode(). ': '. $attr->getFrontend()->getValue($_item)
        );
    }
?>
```

Which produces these (skimmed) results in the log file:

```
2019-12-03T10:23:01+00:00 INFO (6): entity_id: 228
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): type_id: simple
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): attribute_set_id: 4
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): status: Enabled
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): name: Bulb 501 w5w 12v
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): sku: BULB-501-SIN001
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): price: 1.1900
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): ref_code:
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): image_ref:
2019-12-03T10:23:02+00:00 INFO (6): required:
```

As you can see, `ref_code`, `image_ref` and `required` is empty, but I'm not sure why as the values are there in the database. I've tried re-indexing fully and clearing cache via `rm -rf /var/cache/*`

The methods listed in:

- [Magento 2: How to display custom attribute in catalog](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132098/magento-2-how-to-display-custom-attribute-in-catalog)
- [Magento 2: Get custom attribute value of product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157584/magento-2-get-custom-attribute-value-of-product)

didn't work.

I didn't try the Object Manager method as I don't wish to use it as I know it's not the right way to go.

Edit:

snappy of my attribute:

[image]

Edit 2:

I created a module as advised, but couldn't get it 100%. This is the code I implemented:

```
|-app
|-----code
|---------Vendor
|-------------Module
|-----------------etc
|---------------------frontend
|-------------------------di.xml
|---------------------module.xml
|-----------------Plugin
|---------------------Model
|-------------------------Product
|-----------------------------Type
|---------------------------------Grouped.php
|-----------------registration.php
```

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped">
        <plugin name="addAttributes" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Product\Type\Grouped" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
            <module name="Magento_GroupedProduct" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> Grouped.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Product\Type;

class Grouped
{
    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetAssociatedProductCollection($subject, $result)
    {
        $result->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

> registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: try to change scope "Store" to "Global"

Comment: @RkRathod that's what it was to start with :/

Comment: what you mean ??

Comment: @RkRathod as in, I initially set attribute scope = global, but it makes no difference

Comment: @RkRathod see edit

Comment: after changes clean cache

Comment: @RkRathod had already done (and reindexed)

Comment: let me check and try to reproduce in my  system and let you know

Comment: Use the object manager to load the product simply as a test to see if the product actually has the attribute set. If you can see the attribute value that way then you know that the problem is associated with the grouped product child collection.

Comment: @paj using the object manager is a  bad practice I do not wish to indulge ..

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use it as a solution, just as a way to temporarily load the individual product and test the attribute by logging out it's value as you did in your test code. Using the Object Manager as a test is quite safe, your server will not explode...

Comment: @paj I don't want to test if I can get the data via object manager, that would be time wasted, though, I tried doing a similar test using the productfactory and it error'd :S

Comment: Also the title of your question is misleading. Is the product attribute set on the grouped - parent product, or on the associated simple products of the grouped parent? Your code shows you trying to log the attribute value from the associated simple products, not the parent.

Comment: @paj indeed, I don't care about the parent - I want the simple attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `di.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" />
</config>
```

Now you need to create Model file here in your custom module..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped
{
    public function getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
    {
        parent::getAssociatedProductCollection($product);
        $links = $product->getLinkInstance();
        $links->setLinkTypeId(\Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED);
        $collection = $links->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setFlag(
            'product_children',
            true
        )->setIsStrongMode();
        $collection->setProduct($product);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

> Note : Here Vendor is your module's namespace and Module is your module name in above file path.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hey, apologies for long delay! I tried following the steps but it's still not added :/ am I missing a step after adding the above files?

Comment: Have you created new module ? with registration.php and module.xml file ? Or Can you please let me know where you've created this module and how ?

Comment: Hey, I did indeed, can see it as active in /app/etc/config.php

Comment: I'll edit my question with what I did :)

Comment: Yes, this will be helpful to me :) Thanks

Comment: Just finished updating^ :)

Comment: Please move `di.xml` file here **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml** and then run setup upgrade once and check. Hope this will work then.

Comment: No change I'm afraid :/

Comment: Ohh, Please check your di.xml file "Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Product\Type\Grouped" you need to replace this with "Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Product\Type\Grouped". then run setup upgrade and check you'll get output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102021/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-treybake).

Comment: Im pretty sure if we select all attributes, that’s not best practice. @treyBake. This answer is kind of copying from my answer.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh That's just pseudo-names - hopefully people can just add their own attributes in place of the * :) and it does and doesn't, this answer has a Model function overwrite and seems to have a different naming thingy (Plugin and Model vs Model) - so I think they hit on the same idea, but this one seemed to work for me

Comment: That’s fine if working for you. Perfect. I have no idea for now.

Comment: @treyBake, I've updated my answer which is same that worked for you!

Answer (score 5):

[Not sure if it's the correct way]

Take a look at `vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php`

```
public function getAssociatedProducts($product) 
{
   ...
     ->addAttributeToSelect(
                ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id']
   ...
}
```

Seems that Magento just sets some fields.

My suggestion is to use Plugin to add your custom fields. For example:

`app/code/Vendor/CatalogAttributes/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped">
        <plugin name="addAttributes"
                type="Vendor\CatalogAttributes\Model\Plugin\Product\Type\Grouped"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`app/code/Vendor/CatalogAttributes/Model/Plugin/Product/Type/Grouped.php`

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\CatalogAttributes\Model\Plugin\Product\Type;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection;

class Grouped
{
    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param Collection $result
     * @return Collection $result
     */
    public function afterGetAssociatedProductCollection($subject, $result)
    {
        $result->addAttributeToSelect(['ref_code']);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a really counter-intuitive design flaw (on Magento's end) :/ so we have to do this per new attribute we add (that'll be used with grouped products)?

Comment: Setting "used in product listing" should make the attribute value available in all product templates. Your log shows the attribute is recognised, just the value is not available. I don't think this is a solution.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if it's the correct way. Just my finding about this part @paj

Comment: @paj I tried changing that value - no changes, shall procdeed with Khoa's answer :)

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh sorry being a scrub, but how do I then use this in my grouped.phtml file? Do I just amend the block class to point to this one in `catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`?

Comment: @treyBake ah ah, you just use `$_item->getRefCode()` or `$_item->getData('ref_code')`. Remember to echo the value.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh it doth be indeed, I had an idea that I'd extend the Grouped Block class and add in the productFactory and load the product via entity ID (which I have in initial data) and retrieve attr values that way, but it didn't work (due to errors mentioned in that q)

Comment: Do you know how to create a Plugin in Magento? @treyBake

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I know how to do overrides via `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Module/` - but I think I'm missing a step somewhere.. (feel like a missing di.xml maybe)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101848/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-treybake).

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I was curious about this and tested it on my dev store and you are correct - custom attributes must be added to the associated child product collection select if you want to get their values from the type/grouped template.

Comment: Hey, apologies for long delay! I tried following the steps but it's still not added :/ am I missing a step after adding the above files?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer will work with Magento 2.3.3 version. But, you accepted the answer already @treyBake.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh it may have done (although, I think there needs to be some tweaks), but I mainly gave Kishan the acceptance/bounty as he helped me for like 3 hours straight figuring out and the eventual outcome became the solution, not discouraging your answer though! :)

Comment: Ok, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a viewmodel for displaying the custom attribute of the simple products in the grouped.phtml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.grouped.retailbb">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">BA\BasysProdLayouts\ViewModel\GetAttributes</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

ViewModel Class

```
namespace BA\BasysProdLayouts\ViewModel;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class GetAttributes implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    protected $groupCollection;
    protected $logger;
    protected $stockItemRepository;
    private $attrsArray = [];
public function __construct(CollectionFactory $groupCollection, LoggerInterface $logger, StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository)
{
    $this->groupCollection = $groupCollection;
    $this->stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
public function createAttributeArray($groupId, $item)
{
    $productAttributes = $item->getAttributes($groupId);
    $productStock = $this
        ->stockItemRepository
        ->get($item->getId());
    $this->attrsArray['stock'][$item->getId() ] = $productStock->getQty();
    foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute)
    {
        $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $attrValue = $item->getResource()
            ->getAttributeRawValue($item->getId() , $attrCode, $item->getId());
        /* Checking for blank values */
        $finalValue = is_array($attrValue) ? '' : $attrValue;
        $this->attrsArray[$attrCode][$item->getId() ] = $finalValue;
    }
}
public function getLayoutCustAttributes($items)
{
    $groupCollection = $this
        ->groupCollection
        ->create();
    $groupCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name', 'Layout Customizations');
    $groupId = $groupCollection->getFirstItem()
        ->getData('attribute_group_id');
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $this->createAttributeArray($groupId, $item);
    }
    $this->filterEmptyAttributes();
    return $this->attrsArray;
}
private function filterEmptyAttributes()
{
    foreach ($this->attrsArray as $key => $innerArray)
    { //check for each element
        foreach ($innerArray as $innerValue)
        {
            if (!empty($innerValue))
            {
                continue 2; //stop investigating at first non empty, we shoud keep this
                
            }
        }
        //all values in innerArray are empty, drop this
        unset($this->attrsArray[$key]);
    }
}
}
```

In the grouped.phtml

```
        <?php $attrArray = $block->getViewModel()->getLayoutCustAttributes($_associatedProducts);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Attributes in the **getAssociatedProducts()** function using Plugin Method - **afterGetAssociatedProductCollection**

Check this Module to get the selected attributes of child collection

https://github.com/zaxcpro/iamvivek

[image]
This is the Configuration from where you can easily select which attribute to show.

[image: Group]

Group Type is the Attribute i need to show.

[image]
Here group_type is visible in collection.

Github Link - https://github.com/zaxcpro/iamvivek